# Is Ruby's URI.regexp "wrong" to use as a validator?

Tags: java, ruby, rfc2396

Given a url like `https://example.com/<network_id>/1`

[Ruby's URI module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) can validate URIs using a regular expression:

```
URI.regexp.match("https://example.com/<network_id>/1")
=> #<MatchData "https://example.com/" 1:"https" 2:nil 3:nil 4:"example.com" 5:nil 6:nil 7:"/" 8:nil 9:nil>
```

But if you try to hand this off to another package, say [Java's URI class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

It will fail:

```
Error message:
Illegal character in path at index ...

                               java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:73)
...
```

Is there a better URI validator, something that we can use in a Rails class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `URI.parse` to validate a URL. `URL.parse` raises an exception if the URL is not valid:

```
require 'uri'

URI.parse('https://example.com/<network_id>/1')
#=> bad URI(is not URI?): "https://example.com/<network_id>/1" (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

Which allows writing a simple URL validation method like this:

```
def valid_url?(url)
  URI.parse(url) rescue false
end

valid_url?('https://example.com/<network_id>/1')
#=> false

valid_url?('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75179882')
#=> #<URI::HTTPS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75179882>
```

Comment: Also `URI.regexp` and related methods are obsolete [since 2.2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/bb83f32dc3e0424d25fa4e55d8ff32b061320e41). The documentation of `URI` doesn't mention that but running with warnings enabled (`-w`) is always a good idea.